# How do I change my XSLT script so the changes are only made on certain files?

Tags: xslt

Right now my script runs correctly but I want to change it so the script does nothing unless the parameter is present.

Here's my current XSL style sheet snippet of the span I need to delete:

```
<xsl:template match="xhtml:span[@property='atom:tag' and @class='ktp-meta' and normalize-space(.) = 'nclex_rn_qbank']">
        <xsl:param name="content-item-name"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$content-item-name = $input-qid">
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <span property="atom:tag" class="ktp-meta">nclex_rn_qbank</span>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
```

It does delete the span in every instance and when the parameter is not present it adds the span back in. I want to clean it up so it only runs when the content-item-name is entered. How would I do that?

Comment: What kind of value do you pass in when you pass in a value?  With `<xsl:param name="content-item-name"/>`, that is no `select` attribute to give a default value nor a content constructor doing it, I think the implicit default is an empty string (https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#dt-explicit-default, https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#dt-implicit-default). It is not clear what you consider an "entered" value and datatype for the parameter `content-item-name` nor it is clear what kind of value and datatype the other variable or parameter `$input-qid` has.

Comment: I enter a list of numbers in the parameters box in Oxygen. Those numbers are from the <span property="atom:content-item-name" class="ktp-meta" data-value="n023174.mod"></span> in the HTML.

Comment: You have shown a code snippet with two variables? Are both sequences of numbers?

Comment: _"it only runs when the content-item-name is entered"_ The `$content-item-name` parameter will always have value. XSLT Variables and parameters are never set/unset like in imperative paradigms

Answer (score 0):

Supply a default value for `$context-item-name` that will always match `$input-qid`. Thus:

```
<xsl:param name="content-item-name" select="$input-qid"/>
```

so the xsl:when branch is taken when no value is supplied.